# how to check if .exe file exists in php

Tags: php, file, file-exists

Hi there is there any way to check if `.exe` file exists on a given path or not.
I have installation of `ImageMagic`. I have a path of `convert.exe` of Image Magic. I need to check that in given path the `convert.exe` exists or not. I have implemented

```
$settingFileContent = file_get_contents($settingFilePath);
       // print_r($settingFileContent);
        $allPaths = unserialize(stripslashes($settingFileContent));

if (isset($allPaths['IMAGE_CONVERT_EXE'])) {
                //cho $allPaths['IMAGE_CONVERT_EXE'];
                if (file_exists($allPaths['IMAGE_CONVERT_EXE'])) {
                    $analysisResultObj->level = ENUM_SUCCESS;
                } else {
                    $analysisResultObj->level = ENUM_ERROR;
                    $analysisResultObj->infoText = "Image Magic convert.ext has wrong path";   
                 Logger::getLogger('Application')->error('Image Magic convert.ext has wrong path');
                }
            }
```

I can change the value of  `$allPaths['IMAGE_CONVERT_EXE']` in file. When I change to wrong value even in that condition it returns true.

Comment: strange, try using is_file() and see what is the result?

Comment: There is a missing ' after .exe in the first code block.

Comment: @Ghigo It is in question not in code

Comment: you're messing something. The code you posted has to work. Post some real code.

Comment: open a dos prompt and type `dir d:\somfolder\imagemagic\convert.ext` and you should see the file. That's what the function tells you.

Comment: @AwaisQarni but in a comment below you say something like "but in actual code I am using ...". So could you paste something more like your actual code? Maybe you have a typo in one of the variables?

Comment: @Ghigo dos say system cannot find the path

Comment: Post actual code. That's what I meant with "real code". PATH variable doesn't interfere with file_exists().

Comment: @AwaisQarni: this is not possible, can you please post your actual code exactly? not copy one part...

Comment: @Akam Now its real dear

Comment: This code do work. Post some actual code without syntax errors... again, missing a " in echo line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](http://www.php.net/file_exists) comment specifically about PHP on Windows I'm guessing (and let's be clear: **everything** in PHP is a guess) try this:

```
$file = 'd:/somfolder/imagemagic/convert.ext'
if(file_exists($file)) {
    // should be false
}
```

Based on your actual code have you tried:

```
$file = $allPaths['IMAGE_CONVERT_EXE'];
if(file_exists($file)) {
    // should be false
}
```

Looking at the documentation someone commented about having this same problem on Windows and being unable to return the correct result when concatenating string values. While you are not concatenating string values together its at least worth a shot to make sure there isn't something else strange going on.

Comment: nothing in php is a guess if you know what you're doing. I don't like the "magic" approach.

Comment: Read the documentation, it **is** a guess.

Comment: The most dangerous thing you can do on Stack Overflow: write a reasonable answer about a PHP question.

Comment: The most dangerous thing you can do on Stack Overflow: read user comments in PHP documentation and answer a question with them.

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like you're trying to get wether or not the Imagemagick extension exists. PHP provides ways for doing just that thus eliminating your extrapolated and insane approach all together.

```
<?php    
    echo extension_loaded('imagick');
?>
```

Additionally, you can get an idea  of your installed extensions via

```
<?php 
    print_r(get_loaded_extensions()); 
?>
```

Comment: the (supposed) problem is about file_exists() not working correctly.

Comment: this is a valid solution to the problem stated by the questioner